# Sending scheduled emails that include Bugzilla "reports"

Tags: email, report, bugzilla

hi i am new to  Bugzilla.
I intend to send scheduled emails that include report created by me.

I do realize there is something to include *search* results in the email, using the 'Whining' feature provided in the admin section, and I am currently using that.

But is there a way to send Reports that are in the tabular or graph style? These emails are intended to be sent to the Business team and they dont care about the Title or Description of the bug, all they care is about how many products have how many bugs and what priority.

i am able to generate the report as per their liking, but unable to figure out how to inlcude that data in a scheduled email

Comment: Are you intending to do this using Microsoft's SQLServer Reporting Services? The reason I ask is that you have included the reporting-services tag in your question - this tag is specifically for MS SSRS, not for reporting in general.

Comment: oops sorry did not know that, will take it out

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to send reports via email, although is it a long standing request. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35281